# Read in multiple txt files and create a list of it to access each file by accessing the list element in R

Tags: r, list

Being relatively new to R programming I am struggling with a huge data set of 16 text files (, seperated) saved in one dierctory. All the files have same number of columns and the naming convention, for example file_year_2000, file_year_2001 etc. I want to create a list  in R where i can access each file individually by accessing the list elementts. By searching through the web i found some code and tried the following but as a result i get one huge list (16,2 MB) where the output is just strange. I would like to have 16 elements in the list each represting one file read from the directory. I tried the following code but it does not work as i want:

```
path = "~/.../.../.../Data_1999-2015"
list.files(path)
file.names <- dir(path, pattern =".txt")
length(file.names)
df_list = list()
for( i  in length(file.names)){
        file <- read.csv(file.names[i],header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
        year = gsub('[^0-9]', '', file)
        df_list[[year]] = file
}
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without knowing exactly how it differs from what you want then the line `for( i  in length(file.names))` should probably be `for( i  in file.names)` and a corresponding change in `read.csv`. Otherwise you just read in a single file corresponding to the number of files found in the directory

Comment: it's not clear do you want to create a list of data frame and then have access the list elements of do you want to access elements through your loop?

Comment: `filelist <- lapply(file.names, read.csv, header = TRUE, sep = ',', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`and then `names(filelist) <- sapply(file.names, function(fn) gsub('^0-9]', '', fn))` is a more "R-Like" way of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give more details

```
path = "~/.../.../.../Data_1999-2015"
list.files(path)
file.names <- dir(path, pattern =".txt")
length(file.names)
df_list = list()
for(i in seq(length(file.names))){
        year = gsub('[^0-9]', '', file.names[i])
        df_list[[year]] = read.csv(file.names[i],header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

}
```

Maybe it would be worth joining the data frames into one big data frame with an additional column being the year?

Comment: thanks for your tips. it worked perfectly. There is no need to ad an additional column as in the files there is already a column with date including the year. Just  a little discrepency here as the code above reads all the files correclty until year 2013. 2014 is mising and the next file after 2013 is for the year 2015. but it does not read this file and throws the error: > View(df_list[["2015"]])
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds

Answer (score 1):

I assume that instead of "access each file individually" you mean you want to access individually data in each file.

Try something like this (untested):

```
path = "~/.../.../.../Data_1999-2015"
file.names <- dir(path, pattern =".txt")
df_list = vector("list", length(file.names))
        # create a list of data frames with correct length
names(df_list) <- rep("", length(df_list))
        # give it empty names to begin with
for( i  in seq(along=length(file.names))) { 
        # now i = 1,2,...,16
        file <- read.csv(file.names[i],header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
        df_list[[i]] = file
          # save the data
        year = gsub('[^0-9]', '', file.names[i])
        names(df_list)[i] <- year
}
```

Now you can use either `df_list[[1]]` or `df_list[["2000"]]` for year 2000 data.

I am uncertain if you are reading yout csv files in the right directory.  If not, use

```
file <- read.csv(paste0(path, file.names[i], sep="/"),header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

when reading the file.

Comment: thanks. I want to access the data of each individual file to make further tests, and this code should do this. i will test it and then post here if i need some further help. Thanks.

Comment: It works to an extent that I get a df_list variable. when i read all the data files  from the folder, it just reads the file for the year 2000 and all other elements of list are NULL. when i try to explicitly access the file View(df_list[["2001"]]), i get error: > View(df_list[["2001"]])
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds

Comment: Hmm...  It sounds like it only finds the file for year 2000 and nothing else.  What is the output of `dir(path, pattern =".txt")`?  Is your working directory (`getwd()`) the same as `path`?